# Node JS - Access JSON from index.html on button click

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, json.net

I am fairly new to Node JS and I am trying to create a server that when a user navigates to http://localhost:8000/, they are routed to index.html. In that index.html file there will be a button that they can click to obtain JSON data. This JSON data is downloaded onto my own machine with the purpose of being hosted on a Node JS server. There is 6 JSON files.

My question is, can I host the JSON and the index.html on the same server without using a framework like Express? I have a solution in express, but I would like to do so without if possible.

index.html -> press button -> get JSON from server (same server?)

--- EDIT ---

It is for a university module and was given the outlined instructions. Explicitly Node.

Comment: Umm you meant localhost with port 8000 at route '/' is set to render index.html file but where is the json located? In another website?

Comment: Assuming you're using node's `http.createServer(function(req, res) { ... })` for this, you can check `req.url`. If you visit `http://localhost:8000/`, the URL is going to be `/`. If you link to a json file using `<a href="/data1.json">Data 1</a>` then the URL is going to be `/data1.json`. You can use that to deliver the respective file instead of index.html (still, the obvious question is why you don't want to use express, given that in doing so, you will in fact write less code)

Answer (score 1):

Setup environment

```
mkdir server
cd server
npm init
npm install express
touch server.js index.html
mkdir public
```

Server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');

app.use('/public', express.static('public'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});

app.listen(80, () => console.log("Running on: http://localhost"));
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Download JSON</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Download</h1>
    <a href="public/sample.json" download="sample.json">Sample JSON</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Put your JSON in the public folder structure and link to it regularly like in the HTML example above.

Comment: OP says they have a working express based solution and they're asking specifically for a solution *without* express.

Comment: That's silly, so using http lib? Not worth answering

Comment: They might have their reasons, but see the comment I posted above ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can check on express js about static file.
for example:

```
app.use('/static', express.static('public'));
```

more information in:

https://expressjs.com/pt-br/starter/static-files.html

Answer (score 0):

I was overcomplicating the question received. I was told to just use http and fs libraries and access JSON like, localhost/8080/path/to/json.

Apologies for the question.